# Reading current time and increment 1 min for next 2 hrs and run some commands

Tags: shell

1. I have to read current system time and increment 1 min for next 2 hrs. I need to run few commands continuously for 2 hrs with 1 min interval.

for example: current time : 8:30 PM i need to run for next 2 hrs for 8.30, 8.31.... so on for 2 hrs. I am expecting this run should print 120 output results. please help.

Need this in shell script.

Comment: Please read minute where even i have written second.. its typo error.

Comment: Click `edit` under your question to edit it please.

Comment: Don't bother with the current time, just use `$SECONDS` variable - try `echo $SECONDS` and count to 120 with a `for` loop.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick and dirty answer, if you don't mind hard coding 120 minutes in the `for` expression:

```
for min in {1..120}
do
  command &   # launch in background to minimize drift
  sleep 60
done
```

Alternatively, modify crontab entry (avoid all drift considerations):

```
crontab -l > /tmp/oldcron.$$
crontab << EOF
$(crontab -l )
*/2  * * * * command  # run command every 2 minutes forever
EOF
sleep $(( 2 * 60 * 60 ))   # sleep 2 hours
crontab < /tmp/oldcron.$$
```

The above probably suffers by an off-by-1 type of error.  You may need to add 59 seconds to the sleep.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

count=0
max=120 # 2 * 60 minutes

while [ true ]; do
  ((count++))
  sleep 60
  # terminal -e command
  if (( $count > $max )); then
    break
  fi
done
```

Comment: 7 of your 10 lines relate to the loop control, which is far more simply expressed with `for ((i=0;i<120;i++))`. Also, your timing will drift even if each command only takes a second...

Comment: You right, for command time I need to know which distro he is using to replace `terminal`.